# How do I parse LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

I have LLVM IR code in text format. What I wanna do is to be able to parse it and modify that code. Is there an API which can help in parsing the LLVM IR code? What libraries should I have in my system? At this moment I have `clang` compiler installed as well LLVM, as I can use commands such as `llc`, `opt` and `llvm-link`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LLVM is primarily a C++ library. It has all the tools you can imagine to parse, manipulate and produce IR in both textual and bitcode (binary) formats.

To get started, take a look at the `llvm::ParseIRFile` function, defined in header `include/llvm/Support/IRReader.h`.

The best way to proceed would be to download the LLVM source code and build it, following [these instructions](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html). It's then easy to write your own code that uses the LLVM libraries.

Comment: I have llvm 2.7. I can use clang but there is no clang++. Any idea how to add clang++ so I can start using the C++ libraries that you mention?

Comment: @user1018562: you can build LLVM with `gcc`, no real need to have `clang` installed. However, you can also install clang 3.0 which is able to build LLVM itself. See http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

Comment: @user1018562: and by the way, `clang++` is usually just a soft link to `clang`

Comment: @user1018562: see also my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167347/parsing-and-modifying-llvm-ir-code